# Sqlalchemy + sqlite3 | create date using date() with timedelta days taken from CTE column

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a simple calendar using the following method:

```
with Session(DB) as session:
    
    ints = union_all(
        select(literal(1).label('num')),
        select(2),
        select(3),
        select(4),
        select(5),
        select(6),
        select(7),
        select(8),
        select(9),
        select(10),
    ).cte()

    calendar = session.execute(
        select(
            ints.c.num,
            func.DATE(func.current_date(), f'+{ints.c.num} days')
        ).select_from(ints)
    )

    for row in calendar:
        print(row)
```

How do i extract the primitive data type from ints.c.num to create the interval string?
should be something like DATE(CURRENT_DATE, '+1 days'). I really wish Sqlite made this easier.

Stdout:

```
2021-10-10 16:57:50,882 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-10-10 16:57:50,883 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT ? AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10)
 SELECT anon_1.num, DATE(CURRENT_DATE, ?) AS "DATE_1" 
FROM anon_1
2021-10-10 16:57:50,883 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00007s] (1, '+anon_1.num days')
(1, None)
(2, None)
(3, None)
(4, None)
(5, None)
(6, None)
(7, None)
(8, None)
(9, None)
(10, None)
2021-10-10 16:57:50,883 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Try wrapping your f'string' in a SQLAlchemy `text()` function.

Comment: i tried:
```
select(
    func.DATE(func.current_date(), text(f'+{ints.c.num} days'))
).select_from(ints)
```
and
```
select(
    func.DATE(func.current_date(), f'+{text(ints.c.num)} days')
).select_from(ints)
```
to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to cast the column to `String` and concatenate the parts using `+`, which will be converted to sqlite's `||` concatenation operator.

```py
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    ...

    calendar = select(
        ints.c.num,
        func.DATE(func.current_date(), '+' + sa.cast(ints.c.num, sa.String) + ' days')
    ).select_from(ints)
```

The generated SQL is

```sql
WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT :param_3 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10)
 SELECT anon_1.num, DATE(CURRENT_DATE, :param_1 || CAST(anon_1.num AS VARCHAR) || :param_2) AS "DATE_1" 
FROM anon_1
```

Comment: Fantastic! Something to note... apparently this does not work in an f-string as sqlalchemy does not now how to convert this into SQL

Comment: I think `+` is overridden by SQLA in this context to be SQL concatenation rather than Python string concatenation, so an f-string doesn't have the same effect: that is, what's important is that strings are being concatenated, not simply producing a string that looks like the result.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!